# How to call wordpress is_logged_in function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to call this function in JavaScript:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

But the examples are only with PHP. When that JavaScript function is called I want to check if the user is logged and send a message / redirect if not.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your functions.php

```
function check_login() {
    $return['loggedin'] = false;  
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $return['loggedin'] = true;    
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_login', 'check_login');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_login', 'check_login');
```

Add this to your custom JS code

```
$.ajax({
    url : YOUR_AJAX_URL, // "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    cache : false,
    data : {
        action : 'check_login'
    },
    success : function (json) {
        if (json.loggedin) {
            alert("Loggedin");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap javascript code in between php code like below

```
<script>
$('#checkLogin').click(function() {
    <?php if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?>
    alert('Please login to access this page');
    location = 'http://www.example.com';
    <?php else: ?>
    alert('You are logged in');
    <?php endif; ?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: but this only happens if I click on a div

Comment: @user2469440 - what do you mean? You could just do `<script> var loggedIn = <?php echo is_user_logged_in(); ?>; </script>` then use it later: `if(loggedIn){ /* do stuff * / } else { /* redirect */}`.

Comment: Maybe im doing it wrong this what I was thinking: I have a div that onclicked will update mysql table, so I have already stored if there is a user or not BUT when I click on that div I still want to do the mysql update. So I though I had to call a javascript function that would do the mysql update.

Comment: Code updated, you can also use @Joe method, which can be used at multiple place.

Comment: I've been searching and I guess I really need to use ajax. Since I want to update the page without having to reload :| I guess im learning something new today